# How to add centromere information to a Gviz IdeogramTrack object?

Tags: r, plot, bioconductor

I'm using the R Gviz package to plot my deep sequencing data. I'm working with the *Saccharomyces cerevisae* genome. When I add a chromosome ideogram track to my plots the centromere is not plotted.

```
library(Gviz)
sacCerIdeoTrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "sacCer3", chromosome = "chrI")
plotTracks(sacCerIdeoTrack, from = 180e3, to = 220e3)
```

[yields this plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stITA.png)

In contrast, when I do the same using e.g. the human genome the centromere position is indicated.

```
library(Gviz)
humanIdeoTrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "hg19", chromosome = "chrX")
plotTracks(humanIdeoTrack, from=85e6, to=129e6)
```

[yields this plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk6zQ.png)

I assume the *Saccharomyces cerevisae* centromere information is not available from the UCSC online source, from where the `IdeogramTrack` construction function retrievs the data. Is there a way to add the centromere position information manually to my `sacCerIdeoTrack` object?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. I had a look a the cytoband file for hg19 (http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/database/cytoBand.txt.gz) and created a `data.frame` of the same structure containing the information for the *S. cerevisiae* chromosome I.

```
cyto.bands <- data.frame(chrom = rep("chrI", 4),
                         chromStart = c(0, 148071, 151524, 154977),
                         chromEnd = c(148071, 151524, 154977, 230218),
                         name = c(NA, "CEN1", "CEN1", NA),
                         gieStain = c("gneg", "acen", "acen", "gneg"))
```

For the centromere to be printed correctly one needs to supply two rows with `gieStain = "acen"` and sufficient distance between start and end coordinates.

One can then create and plot the Gviz IdeogramTrack object.

```
library(Gviz)

ideogram.track <- IdeogramTrack(chromosome = "chrI", genome = "sacCer3", bands = cyto.bands)

plotTracks(ideogram.track, from = 180e3, to = 220e3)
```

[yielding this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/turKi.png)